# Why Facebook runs every link through a proxy?

Tags: php, facebook, proxy

Why when you post a link to Facebook it will allways come up as in facebook.com/l.php?u=http://linkurlencoded

My common sense tells me it's by some sort of security xss thing, analytics, thing.

Comment: Because facebook is about knowing (and then selling) exactly what everyone is doing at every moment. Allowing people to just leave the site without logging that would hit them in the wallet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is here:

https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-security/link-shim-protecting-the-people-who-use-facebook-from-malicious-urls/10150492832835766

It is a web redirector not meant to be an open redirector with some other tracking stuff.

I also think they do it for security, check this :

http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/601.html

Answer (score 1):

It lets them know when you click a link (since their redirect page can record it). It's probably easier and more reliable than JavaScript tracking. Also, it lets them display warnings that you're leaving Facebook (oh noes!).